# Dropbox upload files to a folder

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using the REST API (C#) to upload files to Dropbox.

I am able to create a folder in Dropbox using the following API:

`https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/fileops/create_folder`

and able to upload a file using

`https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/auto/test.jpg`

How can I upload files to a particular folder?

Here is my code

```
var fileurl = string.Format("https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/fileops/create_folder?root=auto&path=test");

var res = await HttpClient.PostAsync(fileurl,null);
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", backupContent.ContentLength.ToString());

var uploadurl = string.Format("https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/{0}?root=test", fileName);
await HttpClient.PutAsync(uploadurl , Content);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the Dropbox API v1 [/files_put endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files_put), the `path` parameter, which is included in the URL, should include the full path where you want to put the file, including any parent folders.

So, to upload a file named "test.txt" into a folder named "test folder", the `path` would be `/test folder/text.txt`.

You also don't actually need to explicitly create any new parent folders ahead of time. If a parent folder doesn't already exist, it will automatically be created with the upload.